# sending while loop radio button data to database using php

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop

The first two values of the radio are not being inserted, is there any problem with the condition in for loop?

I have the html code(form) and the php code on the bottom

```
<?php 
$i=1;
$name=$data['username'];
$sql1 = "SELECT * from membre where groupe='$name'";
$run1 = mysqli_query($db,$sql1);
                        
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run1)){ 
?>
    <tr>
        <td> <?php echo $i; $i++; ?></td>
        <td style="display: none;" ><input value="<?php echo $i; ?>" name="id[]" class="form-control" readonly="readonly" > </td>
        <td ><input value="<?= $row['nom']; ?>" name="nom1[]" class="form-control" readonly="readonly" > </td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="presence[<?php echo $i; ?>]" value="Présent"></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="presence[<?php echo $i; ?>]" value="Absent"></td>
    </tr>
<?php 
} 
?>
                                        
for($i=0; $i<$_POST['id'][$i]; $i++) {
    $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,trim($_POST['id'][$i]));
    $nom1= mysqli_real_escape_string($db,trim($_POST['nom1'][$i]));
    $presence= mysqli_real_escape_string($db,trim($_POST['presence'][$i]));
    

    $v1 = "INSERT INTO presence(rapport_id,groupe,dat,nom,presence) values('$rapport_id','$groupe','$dat','$nom1','$presence')";
    $r = mysqli_query($db,$v1);
```

Comment: Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: Your script is open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174). 
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187)
You should always use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) 
in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenating user provided values into the query. Never trust ANY user input!

Answer (score 0):

`$i<$_POST['id'][$i]` is not the correct looping condition. You should be using the length of `$_POST['id']` as the loop limit.

Or just use `foreach`. And also use a prepared statement instead of substituting variables directly into the query.

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO presence(rapport_id,groupe,dat,nom,presence) values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param("issss", $id, $groupe, $dat, $nom1, $presence);

foreach ($_POST['id'] as $i => $id) {
    $nom1 = trim($_POST['nom1'][$i];
    $presence = $_POST['presence'][$i];
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

I assume `$rapport_id` in your code should be `$id`.